# "public transport" vs. "public transportation"

Tags: word-choice, american-english, british-english

> 1. Buses are the main form of public transportation
> 2. Buses are the main form of public transport

Which one is correct?

Comment: Transport is usual in British English; Americans add  -ation

Answer (score 4):

In British English, both are correct, and neither is more correct or formal than the other. The first just has a couple of extra syllables. Unsurprisingly, the shorter version is more usual.

Americans seem to prefer the extra syllables.

Comment: Although British English recognises "transportation" as a valid word, it has a distinctly American aroma about it.

Comment: See https://www.english-corpora.org/glowbe/?c=glowbe&q=75093869 for the dialect breakdown (the numbers denote occurrences per million of words).