# Public transport in the US

Tags: usage, dialect

I have learned "public transport" is often used in the UK, while "public transportation" is mainly used in the US.

References

- https://grammarist.com/usage/transport-transportation/
- ["public transport" vs. "public transportation"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/205881/public-transport-vs-public-transportation)

However, I find a CNN article saying "public transport". (Link: https://amp.cnn.com/cnn/2023/07/08/business/free-buses-us-public-transit/index.html)

Can anyone explain why reporters from CNN say "public transport" instead of "public transportation"? Is "public transport" getting more common in the US?

Comment: The only instances of the phrase "public transport" in that article are direct quotations of a representative of the *International Association of **Public Transport***, which is headquartered in Belgium, not in the US. The CNN journalist only used the term "public transit", never "public transport" nor "public transportation". The equivalent American association is rightly called the *American **Public Transit** Association*.